# Javascript quiz app gives error related to radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I am making Javascript Quiz app with radio buttons(they all have names based on corresponding question for example "question1" then next set of buttons are "question2" etc.) and I am able to check the correct answer with

`var answer1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked').value;`

however when I try to assign a variable

`var l = "question";`
`var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);`
`l = l + String(j+1);`
in order to get random question
and declare
`var answer2 = document.querySelector('input[name=l]:checked').value;`
it says

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

even though I double checked with `console.log` that l has the right value. For example on question 1
 `var answer2 = document.querySelector('input[name=l]:checked').value;`
  doesn't work even though l is "question1" while 
`var answer1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked').value;` works.
Thank you in advance and sorry for formatting, I am new on this website.

Answer (score 0):

When you write name=l it is exactly searching for an element with name l. You need to concatenate the string so that the value of l can be inserted. The problem. Is l not being used.

Comment: This is correct, what @Andreas means to say is you need to update your code like this: var answer1 = document.querySelector('input[name='+l+']:checked').value;                                     (OR)                                                                                                                                                                 var answer1 = document.querySelector(`input[name=${l}]:checked`).value //using a template literal

Comment: Thanks Link and Andreas, very helpful!